# Tung oil makes wood look moldy

Tags: tung-oil

I started making some end-grain cutting boards recently, and my first attempt came out far better than I'd imagined. The most recent one, I decided to use Tung Oil instead of mineral oil as a finish, and the board looks like it's moldy. It's a maple/mahogany checkerboard pattern, and a lot of the maple is now discolored and splotchy, and not something I'd want to use or sell.

I sanded to 220 grit, rinsed with clean water to raise the grain, waited 24 hours for it to fully dry, re-sanded to 320 grit, wiped off the dust with a clean rag, and applied diluted tung oil (1:1 with citrus solvent).

Here's the mineral oil, which has the look I want:
[image: maple/cherry, mineral oil finish]

And the tung oil (closeup on areas that look moldy):
[image: maple/mahogany, tung oil finish]

Is it possible to avoid this moldy / dirty look in the future? If so, how? Or is it simply a feature of the wood (the maple, in this case)?

Followup: could this simply be spalting that didn't show until the tung oil was applied?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. First off, great job on that board — joints look good and tight throughout. The blackish stains are unfortunate, but I'm 99% sure it's nothing to do with the tung oil, it just looks native to the wood pieces used (and was emphasised by the oil, which is what oil does). I'd have thought so anyway but the photo showing the board finished in mineral oil, there are small black stains in many of the maple pieces aren't there?

Comment: *"the mineral oil, which has the look I want"* As you've probably already noticed to some degree, you won't get quite the same look that a completely colourless oil gives as you will using tung oil, even if it is a particularly light variety (although less variable than linseed the colour of different pressings of tung still varies quite a bit). And note that tung oil will darken slightly over time, despite its reputation to the contrary.

Comment: The small black dots in the mineral oil board are part of the wood itself - those were evident even when I was sanding. I'm perfectly okay with those.

Comment: I know the looks will differ with different finishes, and overall I'm coming to prefer the tung oil finish look, I'm simply concerned that guests and/or customers will think "Crikey but this board is dirty! Better slap it with some disinfectant real quick!"

Comment: *"The small black dots in the mineral oil board are part of the wood itself"* I'm thinking the mould-looking blackish staining is too. Although I am surprised there was no hint of it when the wood was dry, given the presence of the black dots have you considered that the amorphous stains and the dots are related? Because of course maple wouldn't normally have either.....

Comment: I haven't given it enough thought to have an opinion on their relation. My instinct says no, since the maple in the first cutting board was an entirely different board from the maple in the second (different purchase about 2-ish week apart, even).

Comment: *"My instinct says no, since the maple in the first cutting board was an entirely different board from the maple in the second (different purchase about 2-ish week apart, even)."* Ah, interesting! In that case I too would be less inclined to think they're related. It's a puzzler! Since the mouldy-looking stains do look very like water stains (caused by iron) and I'm sure some observers would think in that direction but the tung shouldn't contain any iron, maple isn't known for being high in tannins (which is what reacts with iron to turn black) and not least because the effect is so localised.

Comment: That gives me an idea for my next board - I rinsed this one in the kitchen sink, using city water. I have no idea what's in my tap water beyond "not stuff that would kill me" - it may have relatively higher iron concentrations. I'm going to find some other way to raise the grain before the final sanding and see what happens with the tung oil then.

Comment: Well there's certainly a chance of some iron in tap water, it's one of the many reasons various craft uses for water suggest *not* using tap water (even boiled) but instead distilled water, even if it's from a dehumidifier or a condensing clothes drier. But the extremely localised discolouration here would not lead me to think iron introduced from the tap water was the cause. And like I say an iron reaction would have to be with tannins..... those are the only areas that have enough? Seems exceedingly unlikely. And elephant in the room: zero reaction in the mahogany, anywhere?

Comment: Could it be picking up some kind of contamination in the shop during processing? I've seen bottom-facing surfaces pick up discoloration/contamination while sanding the opposite surface, for instance.

Comment: It's possible, since my shop is just my garage. Although, I've started another piece with the same maple, and I'm noticing the same kind of stains on the grain areas while I'm just sanding - and they don't fade as I sand, they're pretty constant throughout the thickness of the piece.

Comment: Same happened to me with different types of boards/wood. First I made some artish pieces using *araucaria angustifolia* (Brazilian pine wood) ,cleaned with isopropanol (I never use water for cleaning wood) waited till dry and applied tung polimerized oil. Other board was what we call naval plywood, sanded, dusted and applied tung oil. After one month, both pieces got green mold. I am swearing to never use tung oil but first, what happened?

Comment: Mold artifacts happens when stuff is stored in a closed room with low temperatures and high humidity, either water got trapped in the wood underneath the coating and the piece was stored in a cold environment or either the mold was already there and the oil coat just popped it out, as it usually pops out details that you don't see on surfaces when sanding, cutting or milling. I think it has nothing to do with the oil but with the environment. Unfortunately mold spores are omnipresent.